# Active_Admin Delete not working - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I recently updated to the newest version of active admin and now my delete buttons don't work.  I'm using the standard pages that are generated with out modifications.  I'm getting this error on the browser debugging console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined active_admin.js:9612
(anonymous function) active_admin.js:9612
(anonymous function) active_admin.js:10118

Here is my application.js file.

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll     automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require underscore
```

I use jquery through out my site so I am sure it is being included.

I have run rails generate active_admin:assets many times.  I've been trying to fix this for about 10 hours now and I am stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

Add the below to your HTML code after loading JQuery js library: (occurs when using JQuery version 1.9 and + )

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little late to the game here but this usually happens when you use JQuery around 1.9 and greater. JQuery 1.9 and greater (I think it's around that time) took out the browser sniffing so that's where that error comes from.